# React: Is it safe to return false from shouldComponentUpdate?

Tags: reactjs

I have create a React component that renders it's children into grid markup. Since the component is stateless and the grid markup will never change, is it ok to return `false` from `shouldComponentUpdate`?

My only concern that I of course don't want to prevent the children from re-rendering but only the grid component.

Answer (score 0):

### Stop renders at the source using shouldComponentUpdate

Take a look at this nested Component structure:

[image: Elements Tree]

By default, if an Update is triggered in A, then all the other children will also go through their updates. This can easily cause a performance issue, because now we have many Components going through each step of the process.+

By adding logic checks in shouldComponentUpdate() at A we can prevent all its children from re-rendering. This can improve overall performance significantly. But keep in mind, if you prevent A from passing props down to the children you may prevent required renders from occurring.

*So, Answering your question, if you prevent element A from re-render it will cause a cascade effect and will affect your grid component.*